# Using C# to ignore a value when importing data to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have written code that reads in values from a delimited `.txt` file and then will parse the data and update a SQL Server table. I'm having a problem because my `.txt` file has about 200 rows worth of data except I only need numbers from a couple of them.

I wrote an `if` statement to specify which values I'm looking for and then it puts them in the correct column. My issue is my else statement. Right now I have it set as just a blank string except I don't have a blank string in my table so it is giving me an error when it tries to update it.

How would I go about ignoring the `ELSE` when updating my table?

This is the section of my code that I have the problem with:

```
foreach (var record in records)
{
    Console.WriteLine(record.RESORT);
    Console.WriteLine(record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);

    // This allows us to split what column a row goes into based on whether it is a day and what SUB_GRP_1 it is
    string Heading = record.HEADING_2;
    string Group = record.SUB_GRP_1;
    string column;

    if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC")
    {
        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_PERC_WO_CH")
    {
        column = "Percent_Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM")
    {
        column = "ADR";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ADR_ROOM_WO_CH")
    {
        column = "ADR_minus_Comp_and_House";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOMREV_AVL_ROOMS_MINUS_OOO")
    {
        column = "Revenue_per_Available_Room_minus_OOO";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "TOTAL_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Total_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "ROOM_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Room_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "FOOD_BEV_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Food_And_Beverage_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OTHER_REVENUE")
    {
        column = "Other_Revenue";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "PHYSICAL_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Total_Rooms_in_Hotel";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Rooms_Occupied";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "OCC_MINUS_COMP_HU")
    {
        column = "Rooms_Occupied_minus_Comp_and_House_Use";
    }
    else if (Heading == "DAY" && Group == "COMP_ROOMS")
    {
        column = "Complimentary_Rooms";
    }
    else
    {
        column = "";
    }

    // SQL connection. Creates connection and command and inserts the values taken from the File Helper engine into the SQL table
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlConnection conn;

    conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hureports01;Initial Catalog=hureports;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();

    var sqlCommand = string.Format(@"MERGE [HEWreport] AS target USING (select @Property_ID as Property_ID, @column as {0}) AS source ON (target.Property_ID = source.Property_ID) WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {0}= source.{0} WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Property_ID, {0}) VALUES (source.Property_ID, source.{0});", column);

    cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Property_ID", record.RESORT);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As you can see, I have it set so that each different if statement will change the value of a column, and that value directly relates to a column on my table. However, I can't get it to ignore my else statement and it is giving me an error each time it comes across a row that has a different Heading or Group

Comment: Use the keyword `continue` in the else statement to _not_ execute the SQL. To clarify: the `continue` will just move on to the next `record in records`.

Comment: I did that and got this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Property_ID nvarchar(5),@column nvarchar(4000))MERGE [HEWrepor' expects the parameter '@column', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap an if statement around your sql query

```
if (column != "") // Some people will say that you should use String.Empty()...
{

SQL Code...

}
```

If you will not want to execute *any* code at all after the If, ElseIf code then you can do as commented and use continue to end the iteration of the foreach loop and start the next one if there is one available.

Comment: I got the same error as I got when i tried the other option of just using continue which was : An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: The parameterized query '(@Property_ID nvarchar(5),@column nvarchar(4000))MERGE [HEWrepor' expects the parameter '@column', which was not supplied.

Comment: Your problem is in this statement `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column", record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT);` the @column parameter is not being set. Not the `string column` being blank.

Comment: @MaxSorin how do i fix that? i thought it was being set to record.FORMATTED_AMOUNT

Comment: @Brandont Personally, I would remove the inline SQL completely, replace it with a stored procedure call, and never speak of it again.